# Strange behavior with parsing data in JS

Tags: javascript, parsing, date, datejs

I'm using library [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) and Date.parse() method

When I'm parsing Date.parse('30/07/2012') I'm getting right date Mon Jul 30 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
But when I'm trying to parse Date.parse('01/08/2012') (date 2 days after) I'm getting Sun Jan 08 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
It is switching day and month!

Does anybody know why is that?

I belive it's not a problem is not in Date.js but in JS itself...

Comment: How is July 1 two days after July 30?

Comment: is that supposed to be `Date.parse('01/08/2012')`?

Comment: Firefox tells me that '30/07/2012' is actually Sat, 07 Jun 2014 - it interprets the first field as the month, so it gives me the 30th month of 2012. It's probably a locale thing.

Comment: @Pointy I believe he is referring to the `Date.parse` method of the `Date.js` library though? It should give same result regardless of browser. You can use the textbox here to test: http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: @Esailija yes that's what I was trying to determine - it's definitely something that the library does (and it seems like seriously undesirable behavior, to me)

Comment: Sorry, yes it supposed to be ('01/08/2012').

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that date.js is smart enough to realize that `30` is not a valid month, so it switches itself to dd/mm/yyyy format.

the default format, however, would be mm/dd/yyyy, and it DOES recognize `01` as a valid month (January) so it gives you january 8th instead of august 1st.

to fix this, just specify a format string you are using:

```
Date.parse('30/07/2012', 'MM/dd/yyyy');
```

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation

Comment: Yes it's definitely something that Date.js is doing - this scenario can be reproduced on the Date.js home page in their demo.  I'm not sure I'd call it "smart" however :-)

Comment: @Pointy agreed. smart is one thing, but this is too magical for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting is probably wrong ("mm/dd/yyyy") instead of ("dd/mm/yyyy").

when you used 30 for your month, the library parsed it as a day, but in the next case, there's no excuse, and you get parsed as a month instead of a day.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the hints.

Actual solution is to use , **Date.parseExact()** and specify input of date. 
In this case it is `Date.parseExact('01/08/2012', "d/M/yyyy")`